# How to run integration tests against through Nginx server + Thin on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, nginx

I have a `Rails 4` integration test which is running and passing as I speak. It runs on `Ruby Thin` server. Now, I have configured `Nginx` server which is proxying all the requests and I want my integration test to point to `Nginx` server and run as they would run directly on `Thin` server.

The integration test are ran using following command:

```
rake test:integration TEST=test/integration/login_test.rb
```

How to configure my integration tests so that they can run and pass with `Nginx` acting as the request handler proxy?

```
Old: Integration Test -> Thin Server                 (TESTS PASSING FINE !!!!)
New: Integration Test -> Nginx Server -> Thin Server (HOW TO CONFIGURE TESTS ????)
```

My Nginx server is already up and running with name: `www-mynginx-server.com`

**login_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class LoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  setup do
    @user = users(:admin)
  end

  test "login page is displayed on root path" do
    delete '/signout'
    get root_path
    assert redirect?
    assert_redirected_to '/signin'
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template :new
    assert_template %r{\Adevise/sessions/new\Z}
    assert_select "a[href=?]", users_path, count: 0
    assert_select "input[id=?]", 'user_email', count: 1
    assert_select "input[id=?]", 'user_password', count: 1
    assert_select "input[value=?]", 'Log in', count: 1
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a site in nginx (probably `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite` - depends on your OS), with a proxy (a minimal config):

```
server {
      listen 80;    
      server_name _;

      location / {    
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # replace your thin server port
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3040; 
      }   
}
```

Enable the site:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite
```

and reload nginx:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

There are many ways how to modify the name of server. For integration test you have a several [helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing) available, use `host!` to modify server URI of each request:

```
class LoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    host! 'www-mynginx-server.com'
    #...
  end
  # ...
end
```

or in `spec_helper.rb` modify default:

```
before(:each) do
  default_url_options[:host] = 'www-mynginx-server.com'
end
```

or definition of an environment variable `SERVER_NAME` or `DEFAULT_HOST` would have the same effect (see [the code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2de361177f934ffb63bbaa04b7f0637a9a14eea2/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb#L279)), e.g.:

```
ENV['SERVER_NAME'] = 'www-mynginx-server.com'
```

Comment: Tombart - I already have the application deployed and accessible through using both standalone Tiny server and Nginx + Tiny combined. So `http://10.0.2.15:3000/signin` works and `www-mynginx-server.com/sigin` also works. What I want to know is what config changes I need to do in my Rails tests configuration so that it can interpret and hit Nginx server.

Comment: @user2325154 Sorry, I've overlooked that. I've updated the answer, if you want this just for integration test, I'd go for the first option.

Comment: @Tom- Thanks for the update. I specified `host! 'www-mynginx-server.com'` in my `test_helper.rb` file and I got following error message when I ran the test `NoMethodError: undefined method `host!' for ActiveSupport::TestCase:Class`

Comment: I could get it to work by putting it inside the actual test 'login_test.rb' :) However, I have a bunch of tests. Do I need to put this inside all the other tests as well?

Comment: @user2325154 `host!` will work only in integration tests, to make it global try using ENV variable.